# Java, how to make duallist

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code. Trully i am trying to learn java but i don't get it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



public class Dual{
    public static JFrame myframe;
    public JPanel mypanel;
    private JList sourceList;

      private DefaultListModel sourceListModel;

      private JList destList;

      private DefaultListModel destListModel;

      private JButton addButton;

      private JButton removeButton;





    public Dual(){
        myframe = new JFrame("Dual List Box");
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(myframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myframe.setSize(400, 300);
        myframe.setResizable(false);
        mypanel = new JPanel();
        myframe.getContentPane().add(mypanel);
        initScreen();
        data();
    }

    private void initScreen() {
        mypanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        sourceListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        sourceList = new JList(sourceListModel);

        addButton = new JButton(">>");
        addButton.addActionListener(new AddListener());
        removeButton = new JButton("<<");
        //removeButton.addActionListener(new RemoveListener());

        destListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        destList = new JList(destListModel);

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.add(new JLabel("Available Elements:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        leftPanel.add(new JScrollPane(sourceList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        leftPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Selected Elements:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        rightPanel.add(new JScrollPane(destList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rightPanel.add(removeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mypanel.add(leftPanel);
        mypanel.add(rightPanel);






      }
    private void data(){
        //sourceListModel.firstElement(request.getParameter("t" + i));
        sourceListModel.addElement("ABC");
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Four", "Five", "Six" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen" });
        sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "Nineteen", "Twenty", "Thirty" });
        sourceListModel.addElement("GREHDH");
        destListModel.addElement("DER");
        destListModel.addElement("GRTD");
        destListModel.addElement("HRET");
    }

    private void showSourceSelected() {
        Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
        System.out.println(selected.length); 
        for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            System.out.println(selected[i]);
          }
    }
    private void change1Selected() {
        Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
        int descout = destList.getModel().getSize();
        int c = 0;
        //System.out.println(selected.length); 
        for (int i = descout + 1; i <=selected.length+descout; i++) {
            destListModel.addElement(selected);

            destListModel.addElement("belble"+c);
            c++;
        }
        for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            sourceListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);

            //System.out.println(selected[i]);
          }
        //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

    }
        //myframe = new JFrame("Dual List Box ");
    //myframe.;
    private class AddListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
          showSourceSelected();
          change1Selected();
          //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
          //addDestinationElements(selected);
          //clearSourceSelected();
        }
      }
}
```

Left button is running, as in topic i am trying to make duallist. 
I don't know how to handel a single or multiply selection. 
How to make adding a single or multiplay elements.
How to switch betwen list without funny jlang.object or string blabla.

Based on: [Dual List Box](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DualListBoxSample.htm) Sample : Dual List « Swing « Java Tutorial

---

Edited
New Code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;



public class Dual{
public static JFrame myframe;
public JPanel mypanel;
private JList sourceList;

  private DefaultListModel sourceListModel;

  private JList destList;

  private DefaultListModel destListModel;

  private JButton addButton;

  private JButton removeButton;

public Dual(){
    myframe = new JFrame("Dual List Box");
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(myframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myframe.setSize(400, 300);
    myframe.setResizable(false);
    mypanel = new JPanel();
    myframe.getContentPane().add(mypanel);
    initScreen();
    data();
}

private void initScreen() {
    mypanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    sourceListModel = new DefaultListModel();
    sourceList = new JList(sourceListModel);

    addButton = new JButton(">>");
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddListener());
    removeButton = new JButton("<<");
    removeButton.addActionListener(new RemoveListener());

    destListModel = new DefaultListModel();
    destList = new JList(destListModel);

    ListSelectionListener listener1 = new ListSelectionListener(){

        JList b = null;

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println(sourceselcted());
            if(e.getSource().equals(sourceList)){
            System.out.println("Source selcted");

                if(b!=e.getSource()){

                    destList.clearSelection();
                }
            }
            else{
            System.out.println("Destination selcted");
            if(b!=e.getSource()){

                sourceList.clearSelection();
            }
            }
            b=(JList) e.getSource();
            //System.out.println(b);
        }
        }

    };
    destList.addListSelectionListener(listener1);
    sourceList.addListSelectionListener(listener1);

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    leftPanel.add(new JLabel("Available Elements:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    leftPanel.add(new JScrollPane(sourceList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    leftPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Selected Elements:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    rightPanel.add(new JScrollPane(destList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    rightPanel.add(removeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    mypanel.add(leftPanel);
    mypanel.add(rightPanel);
    /* sourceList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        int lastSelectedIndex;

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            int index = sourceList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());

            if (index != -1 && index == lastSelectedIndex) {
                sourceList.clearSelection();
            }

            lastSelectedIndex = sourceList.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });

    */




  }
private void data(){
    sourceListModel.addElement("ABC");
    sourceListModel.addElement("One" );
    sourceListModel.addElement("Four");
    sourceListModel.addElement("Seven");
    sourceListModel.addElement("Ten");
    sourceListModel.addElement("Thirteen");
    sourceListModel.addElement("Sixteen");
    sourceListModel.addElement("Nineteen");
    sourceListModel.addElement("GREHDH");
    destListModel.addElement("DER");
    destListModel.addElement("GRTD");
    destListModel.addElement("HRET");
}

private void showSourceSelected() {
    Object selectedcount[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
    System.out.println(selectedcount.length); 
    for (int i = selectedcount.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.println(selectedcount[i]);
      }
}
private void showSourceSelected2() {
    Object selectedcount[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
    System.out.println(selectedcount.length); 
    for (int i = selectedcount.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.println(selectedcount[i]);
      }
}
private int countlist(JList list){
    return list.getSelectedValues().length;

}
private void change1Selected() {
    Object selectedcount[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
    int count = selectedcount.length;
    Object selected = sourceList.getSelectedValue();
    //int descout = destList.getModel().getSize();
    //int c = 0;
    //System.out.println(selected.length); 
   // for (int i = descout + 1; i <=descout+1; i++) {
    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
        destListModel.addElement(selectedcount[i]);
        sourceListModel.removeElement(selectedcount[i]);

   // }
   // for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

    }   
        //System.out.println(selected[i]);
      //}
    //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();      
}
private void change2Selected() {
    Object selectedcount[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
    int count = selectedcount.length;
    Object selected = destList.getSelectedValue();
    //int descout = destList.getModel().getSize();
    //int c = 0;
    //System.out.println(selected.length); 
   // for (int i = descout + 1; i <=descout+1; i++) {
    for(int i=0;i<=count-1;i++){
        sourceListModel.addElement(selectedcount[i]);
        destListModel.removeElement(selectedcount[i]);

        //destListModel.addElement("belble"+c);
        //c++;
   // }
   // for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

    }   
        //System.out.println(selected[i]);
      //}
    //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

}

private class AddListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
      //showSourceSelected();

      System.out.println(countlist(sourceList));
      change1Selected();
      //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
      //addDestinationElements(selected);
      //clearSourceSelected();
    }
  }
private class RemoveListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
      //showSourceSelected2();

      System.out.println(countlist(destList));
      change2Selected();
      //sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
      //addDestinationElements(selected);
      //clearSourceSelected();
    }
  }
private boolean sourceselcted() {
    int sourcelength = sourceList.getSelectedValues().length;
    if(sourcelength>=1)return true;
  return false;    
}
private boolean destselcted() {
    int sourcelength = destList.getSelectedValues().length;
    if(sourcelength>=1)return true;
  return false;    
}

}
```

How to sort?? Are there any ready functions, or i had to make it myself??
What are Jlist with Object//String declarations??
What are difrences betwen DefaultListModel,AbstractListModel,ListModel and when to use what??
How to make Jlist with subtype data ABC - Name: xxx,ForVesrion: yyy,Type: zzz; and get sorting by xxx or yyy or zzz or any other  yyy/zzz/xxx..??

Answer (score 1):

> How to switch betwen list without funny jlang.object

Why did you change the code for the example? The original code uses a custom ListModel. Your code uses the DefaultListModel.

By default a JList just invokes the `toString()` method on any element added to the ListModel.

```
sourceListModel.addElement(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
```

Your code is adding an Array to the ListModel. The `toString()` method of an Arry will display data like "jlang.object".

The original code added the individual elements of the Array to the ListModel.

So the solution is to NOT add an Array to the ListModel. Instead you need to add each element separately:

```
sourceListModel.addElement("One");
sourceListModel.addElement("Two");
sourceListModel.addElement("Three");
```

Comment: Well, thts one thing but still :
destListModel.addElement(selected); givesj.lang.object@6346t7832678

Comment: @MrNice, What did I just tell you? You can't add an Array to the ListModel. "selected" is an Array!!! You need to add the items in the Array to the ListModel.

Comment: Well i often see examples with <xyz> listmodel,JList- what that means
If i wanted to make use it more reliable, i wana make a loader, and read some name from files like example:
mod1 name:1234
mod2 name:7890
and when duallist ready send list to load to execute or move to unload. Can it be done with DefaultListModel??

Comment: @MrNice, I have no idea what you are asking, and neither do other people since the question has been closed because `it is unclear what you are asking`. The ListModel takes one Object at a time. If you are asking how to add an Object to a ListModel that contains multiple different properties, then you would need to create a custom renderer to display the appropriate property from the Object. Take a look at [ComboBox With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information. Concept of using a renderer is the same for a JList.

Comment: Also, if you have more information to add to your question, then edit your question.

Comment: Edited.. second part avalaiable.